# Stop program flow with Ext.Msg Extjs 4.1.1

Tags: extjs, tabs, extjs4, sencha-touch

As the title says, I need to capture the change event of a tab and show to the user a confirm message box. I achieved this but using the **confirm** JS native function. I'd like to perform this using ExtJS's **Ext.Msg.show()**, but the program flow does not stop with this way, as it does with **confirm** function. See below the two ways:

'Ext.Msg.show()' way:

```
onBeforeTabChange: function(panel, nextTab, oldTab) 
    {
        var bReturn = true;
        if (null != oldTab)  
        { 
            if(AppGlobals.isEditing=='si')
            {
                Ext.Msg.show(
                {
                    title: 'Warning', 
                    msg: 'Leave without saving changes?',
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
                    icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING,
                    closable: false,
                    buttonText: 
                    {
                        yes : 'Yes, sure',
                        no : 'No, will save changes first'                
                    },
                    fn: function (buttonId)
                    {
                        if(buttonId=="yes")
                        {
                            AppGlobals.isEditing = 'no';
                            bReturn = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bReturn = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                bReturn = true;
            }
        }
        return bReturn;
    }
```

As I said before, the code above does not stop the program flow. The alert appears but the tab changes anyway.

'confirm' way:

```
onBeforeTabChange: function(panel, nextTab, oldTab) 
    {
        var bReturn = true;
        if (null != oldTab)  
        { 
            if(AppGlobals.isEditing=='si')
            {
                bReturn = confirm('Leave without saving changes?');
                if(bReturn==true)
                {
                    AppGlobals.isEditing = 'no';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                bReturn = true;
            }
        }
        return bReturn;
    }
```

The code above do work, and the tab does not change until user clicks on "Yes".

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ext.Msg.show()` is **asynchronous** and doesn't stop execution of the rest of program. The solution would be **always return false** from `beforetabchange` listener and **programmatically change** the tab when user press **Yes**.

**A Sample Code:** Here i have used `allowChange` as flag to prevent showing of message box when tab is changed programmatically. You can use you own flag here which i  suppose is `AppGlobals.isEditing`

```js
Ext.application({
  launch: function() {
    var allowChange = false;
    Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
      width: 300,
      height: 200,
      activeTab: 0,
      items: [{
          title: 'Tab 1',
          bodyPadding: 10,
          html: 'A simple tab'
        },
        {
          title: 'Tab 2',
          html: 'Another one'
        }
      ],
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      listeners: {
        beforetabchange: function(tabPanel, nextTab, oldTab) {
          var bReturn = true;
          if (null != oldTab && !allowChange) {
            bReturn = false;
            Ext.Msg.show({
              title: 'Warning',
              msg: 'Leave without saving changes?',
              buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
              icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING,
              closable: false,
              buttonText: {
                yes: 'Yes, sure',
                no: 'No, will save changes first'
              },
              fn: function(buttonId) {
                if (buttonId == "yes") {
                  allowChange = true;    // to stop showing the message box again when tab is changed programmaticaly
                  tabPanel.setActiveTab(nextTab);

                }

              }
            });

          }
          allowChange = false;
          return bReturn; // always return false
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great!! Just what I needed